# jQuery .numeric and pasting content

Tags: php, jquery, validation, numeric

The .numeric function (http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/) works great, but when you paste content into the txtOrderName field and you exit the field it doesnt validate.

Does anyone know any modifications that will allow the .numeric function to be run again after content has been pasted?

For example, if I paste '4,00' into the txtOrderPrice field, I dont want the comma (,) to be displayed. The numeric function ignores this if you type '4,00' in the field (changes to '400'). But knowing people they might just paste '4,00' into the field and stuff things up.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.numeric.js"></script>
  $(document).ready(function() {    
    $(".numeric").numeric();
  });
</script>

<input class="numeric" type="text" id="txtOrderPrice" name="txtOrderPrice_name" maxlength="128" />
```

Answer (score 2):

it says it's the limitation:

> **Limitations / Bugs** CTRL+A does not select all text. Text pasted via
>   the mouse is not auto-corrected, though a callback can be defined to
>   work around this.

so, the workaround would be to hook it up to either .blur() or .focusout() event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".numeric").numeric();
    $(".numeric").focusout(function() {
        $(this).keyup();
    });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xFJfP/

Comment: thanks! your help pointed me into the right direction.
note to self: always remember to check that you have the latest version of js files. I was using numeric.js v1.2 instead of v1.3

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the `,` with a `.` like so:

```
value.replace(/,/g,".");
```